# AngularJS : How to make my Controller variable available on all page context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work with angularjs. In one of my view controller, i initialize one of my variable recipesData.
Here is the controller :

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('myApp')
        .controller('CookController', CookController);

    CookController.$inject = ['$document','$scope','$rootScope','$window'];

    function CookController ($document,$scope,$rootScope,$window) {

        var vm = this;


        var recipesData = load();


        var viewer, ui, building;

        $scope.load = function ()  {
           var data;
           // create data 
           // ..........
            return data;
        };

    };

})();
```

I want to make my variable recipesData global. I have an external script which expects this variable initialized.

```
<script src="https://myexternal/lib/js/script.js"></script>
```

How to make it global or make it available from script imported on head ? My variable is initialized from my controller.

Thanks

Comment: use `rootscope` or make a `service` for that , best solution is `service`.

Comment: yep as he @chiragsatapara mentioned `$rootscope.recipesData` will do your work

Comment: @chiragsatapara: you should turn that into an answer

Comment: Don't use $rootScope. As @chiragsatapara says a `service` is the best solution.

Comment: `$window.recipesData = recipesData;` will expose the variable as global.

Comment: let me share a sample `service` for that

Comment: @pracede, this solution is helpful to you?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this using `rootscope` and using `service` , but best solution is using a **`service`**. 
Here is sample service code, make your service according to your requirement.

```
 fcty.service('taskService', function() {
    var task = {};
    var addTask = function(newObj) {
        task = newObj;
    }

    var getTask = function() {
        return task;
    }
    return {
        addTask: addTask,
        getTask: getTask,
    };
});
```

add `taskService` in controller

```
cntrl.controller('taskCreateController', function($scope, $http,taskService) {

// Add to service.

taskService.addTask($scope.data);

// Get from service in any controller by adding taskservice.

taskService.getTask();


}
```

This service is as per your requirement.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.service('recipeService', function() {
    var recipeData = {};
     var addRecipe = function(newObj) {
        recipeData = newObj;
    }

    var getRecipe = function() {
        return recipeData;
    }
 return {
        addRecipe: addRecipe,
        getRecipe: getRecipe,
    };

});


app.controller('CookController', function($scope, $http, recipeService) {

  var vm = this;
  var viewer, ui, building;

        $scope.load = function ()  {
           var data;
           // create data 
           // ..........
            recipeService.addRecipe(data);
            return data;
        };

});
```

Hope this example is helpful to you.

Answer (score 1):

Three AngularJS ways for this:

(Listing them in priority of their usage)

1. Using service/factory as explained by @chiragsatapara
2. Using event $rootScope.$emit and listening it using $rootScope.$on
3. Using $rootScope