# How to pass the value into other controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I don't think this information is enough to completely make sense but I just some direction on this. or if you want I can share the complete code with you in floobit**

I am trying to put this array from API into a seller array.

```
    this.fetchSellers = function () {
        var date = new Date().toISOString();
        $http.get('/api/sellers', {params: {auctionDate: date}})
            .success(function (sellers) {
                sellers && sellers.length && ($scope.sellers = sellers);
            });
    };
```

I am trying to put this one of the value **Seller.symbol** into the array list below. 
 [image]

```
$scope.sellers = []
```

It able to load into ng-option like

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="auction.seller" ng-options="o.id as o.symbol for o in sellers" required></select>
```

[image]

**But** the question is, I am not able to pass the value into another controller in the table.
[image]

code for HTML

```
   <tbody class="auction-group" ng-repeat="a in auctions">
    <tr>
        @*auction *@
    <td>{{ acv('auctionDate', a) }}</td>
        @*seller*@
    <td>{{ a.seller }}</td>
```

Code for ng

```
 this.tableComplexFieldDict = {

        auctionDate: {
            label: 'Auction',
            cacheKey: 'auctionDate',
            getCacheValue: function (a) {
                return moment(a.startAt).format('MM/DD/YY');
            }
        },

        facility: {
            label: 'Facility',
            cacheKey: 'facility',
            getCacheValue: _.property('contract.facility')
        },

        seller: {
            label: 'Seller',
            cacheKey: 'seller',
            getCacheValue: function (a) {
                return a.seller;
            }
        },
```

Comment: You can write a Service for it and can call from different created controller.

Comment: Uhm, thanks for the comment, can you be more specific?

Comment: @Abhay Dixit I got a seller-service, but how am I pass the value? create a scope or function, I am sort of new to this...

Comment: If you want to share your scope between controllers, please go through it https://gonzalo123.com/2014/09/08/sharing-scope-between-controllers-with-angularjs/

Comment: check this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45301127/angularjs-how-to-make-my-controller-variable-available-on-all-page-context/45301350#45301350

Comment: Use broadcast please

Comment: Thanks, all. for the answers , is there any way to store my API into $scope.sellers = []
?

Answer (score 1):

in order to do that you have to use another service. Ideally, you can pass data between controller to service vice versa. so just create another service and include it in which ever controller you want to pass data to.

here is [example](http://jsbin.com/qovagim/edit?html,js,output)

or

```js
// declare the app with no dependencies
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);


myApp.factory('Data', function(){
    return { FirstName: '' };
});

myApp.controller('one', function( $scope, Data ){
 $scope.Data = Data;
});

myApp.controller('two', function( $scope, Data ){
 $scope.Data = Data;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular/master/angular.min.js"></script>
  
</head>
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <h3>write something in text box it will be printed by both controller</h3>
  <div ng-controller="one">
   <input type="text" ng-model="Data.FirstName"><!-- Input entered here -->
   <br>Controller 1 : <strong>{{Data.FirstName}}</strong><!-- Successfully updates here -->
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div ng-controller="two">
   Controller 2: {{Data.FirstName}}<!-- How do I automatically updated it here? -->
  </div>

 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what to do when I only wanna pass everything in the API as an array? store array into $scope.sellers = []

Comment: yes you can store in a single array and pass in service so the code will be easy to handle instead of passing multiple values

Comment: how do i pass it in like this $scope.sellers = ["12312", "2324", "B23244", "2322en"] only the symbols

Comment: why to hard code like that. put it inside some scope and pass to where ever you want to. create an array I would suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Passing data between controllers can be done in 3 ways:

- Shared service both controllers use with set get data functions
- Using direct data binding through root scope as a medium to store read data from

(terrible abusage of root scope)

- through events

For me, best practice is Using a store and read service ;)

Comment: is there any way to store my API into $scope.sellers = [] ?

Comment: What do you mean by API? You cannot store actual API, it's an access point on the server, it would be like you asked me could you store a graphic card in your service? (well not 100% like that but still)

Comment: Do you wanna store data pulled from it in some special service like a catche? Yes, but there are better options for catching. If you ask can you store API URLs to a different service, and then use them in other services answer is yes. Hardcode all your API URLS to one service name it URLListService and make a getter for it via some keymap then use it in othe services?

Comment: YES, but I wouldn't bother doing that since you mostly use same API URL in same service not in 10 different ones. SO why not hardcode it there :)